# How can i design y=log(x) in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

i need to write a code in verilog but i'm new to it. I've actually tried $log10() function but when synthesize the code i get an error "Unsupported System Function Call" for $log10().

Comment: Maybe you should start off by designing a floating point arithmetic for 8 bit floating with 3 significant digits.

Comment: *y output is going to be 8-bits, and it will be fixed-point with 3 digits decimal and 5 digits fractional. Y output is going to be in the interval [0,8).* Your constraints appear contradictory. Perhaps that shoulbe be 'binary digits' instead of 'digits decimal'? A value of x = 1024 isn't expressible in 10 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using a power series approximation? You could break it up into a piece-wise function for greater accuracy

See the Wolfram Mathematica screenshot below (click on it for a better view).

[image]

Maybe something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only 1024 possible inputs, I'm lazy enough that I would just do a lookup table. You can generate the module with the following Python code:

```py
import math
import bitstring

s = """
module log10(
   input  wire [9:0]  x,
   output reg  [32:0] y
);

always @*
case (x)
"""

for i in range(1, 1024):

    # this will give you 32b floating point, not 8b fixed
    # point but you can figure that part out

    s += str(i) + ": y = 32'b" + bitstring.BitArray(float=math.log10(i), length=32).bin + ";\n"

s += """
default: y = 32'hdeadbeef;
endcase
endmodule
"""

print(s)
```

Gives you:

```vb
module log10(
   input  wire [9:0]  x,
   output reg  [32:0] y
);

always @*
case (x)
1: y = 32'b00000000000000000000000000000000;
2: y = 32'b00111110100110100010000010011011;
3: y = 32'b00111110111101000100100100111101;
4: y = 32'b00111111000110100010000010011011;
5: y = 32'b00111111001100101110111110110011;
// ...
6: default: y = 32'hdeadbeef;
endcase
endmodule
```